# MissingMemberHandling.Error interceptor in Newtonsoft Json.Net

Tags: json.net

(Thinking in the last paragraph caused me to change the subject of this question)

I wondered if anyone knows of any feature built into Json.Net which allows you access to both the partially (first pass) constructed object as well as the json data.

So that only if some parts of the json are not deserialized in the default behavior, I would have the ability to do extra processing to get the desired output?

The `ContractResolver` has access to only the target types, the `JsonConverter`s have access to the json and the target type, but must create the instance of that type and has limited access to the `serializer` methods that would normally run.

I've tried looking at the source code for such a thing, but haven't seen any calls.  But thought I'd see if anyone else knows of a feature like this.

---

I seem to often find wanting to use the default deserialization behavior for 95% of an object, but just do one part differently, or have a small amount of post-processing.  This becomes extra tricky when wanting to set `MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error` because any custom `JsonConverter` will by-pass that checking (unless you manually do all the `reader.Read()` calls, instead of `JObject.Load(reader)`)

---

For a specific example, I want to be able to deserialize these two json bodies into the same model:

```
{
  "Metadata": {
    "DateAccessed": "2018-07-06 15:59:55"
  },
  "Data": {
    "2018-07-06 15:59:55": { "value": 324 },
    "2018-07-05 15:59:55": { "value": 312 }
  }
}


{
  "Meta Data": {
    "DateAccessed": "2018-07-06 15:59:55"
  },
  "Processed": {
    "2018-07-06 15:59:55": { "value": 12.34 },
    "2018-07-05 15:59:55": { "value": 11.12 }
  }
}
```

My first attempt was to build a custom `ContractResolver` which would recognize a custom attribute `[MultiNameProperty("Metadata", "Meta Data")]` and `[MultiNameProperty("Data", "Processed")]`, but that was not sustainable.

It would be great to have it setup so that default cases could work, but instead of having `JsonSerializationException` throw due to `MissingMemberHandling.Error`, it could first try calling a handler for that...

But is there any alternatives to adding that in currently built-into Newtonsoft Json.Net?

Comment: a simple idea without using converter would be to create a second property but have a setter to set it to the first one - may be? wouldnt that work?

Comment: Yes that would work, but I wanted to avoid dirtying the object like that.  A good midle-ground probably would be to use protected or something which would avoid dirtying the public interface at least.  Although in this exercise I'd like to avoid even that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best, more general, option for this would be to use a [`[JsonExtensionDataAttribute] private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonExtensionDataAttribute) to handle the unknown members, and a `[OnDeserialized]` to post-process anything

The solution I ended up with for the problem at hand was [building a custom `JsonConverter`](https://github.com/Eibwen/SimpleAlphaVantage/blob/master/SimpleAlphaVantage/Utilities/SerializationClasses/BaseResponseDataJsonConverter.cs) and just expecting there would be 2 top-level properties on all the responses I was getting for this case, allowing the second one to have any name it wants to have

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the JSON first to a `JObject`, tune it and deserialize it to the desired model:

```cs
public static Model Parse(string jsonString){
    var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);    
    Normalize(obj);
    return obj.ToObject<Model>();
}

public static void Normalize(JObject obj){
    if (obj["Metadata"] == null)
    {
        obj["Metadata"] = obj["Meta Data"];
        obj.Remove("Meta Data");
    }

    if (obj["Data"] == null)
    {
        obj["Data"] = obj["Processed"];
        obj.Remove("Processed");
    }
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TtMYaq

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and causing me to post my own answer), I forgot about it and never updated what I ended up using.  My goal was to avoid any double-deserialization (mostly just as a challenge), other than that your solution is completely viable!